# How to use a list of dictionaries as function arguments

Tags: python, list, dictionary, arguments

I started out with this code:

```
import bs4, requests

def bal(address, symbol, name):
        r = requests.get('https://bitinfocharts.com/' + name + '/address/' + address)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        elems = soup.find('div', itemprop = 'offers').contents[0].text
        elems = elems.replace(symbol,'').strip()
        return(elems)

print(bal('3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r', 'BTC', 'Bitcoin'))
print(bal('LQL9pVH1LsMfKwt82Y2wGhNGkrjF8vwUst', 'LTC', 'Litecoin'))
```

Which works and generates:

```
174,631.39464194
897,135.38526651
```

However, this function will need to be run across a large set of dictionaries, so I attempted to modify the code and place the data in dictionaries and then made list of the dictionaries to be passed as function arguments.

```
import bs4, requests

wallet1 = {
    'address' : '3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r',
    'symbol' : 'BTC',
    'name' : 'Bitcoin',
    }

wallet2 = {
    'address' : 'LQL9pVH1LsMfKwt82Y2wGhNGkrjF8vwUst',
    'symbol' : 'LTC',
    'name' : 'Litecoin',
    }

wallets =  [wallet1, wallet2]

def bal(address, symbol, name):
        r = requests.get('https://bitinfocharts.com/' + name + '/address/' + address)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        elems = soup.find('div', itemprop = 'offers').contents[0].text
        elems = elems.replace(symbol,'').strip()
        return(elems)

print(bal(wallets))
```

And I got  the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tfountain/Desktop/python_work/stack.py", line 46, in <module>
    print(bal(wallets))
TypeError: bal() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'symbol' and 'name'
>>>
```

Where exactly am I going wrong here?

How should one go about using a list of dictionaries as function arguments?

Comment: You're currently passing the dictionary as the first argument, `address`. Either rewrite the method to take a single dictionary, or use `bal(**wallet)` to unpack the dictionary to separate arguments.

Comment: You didn't change the implementation of `bal` at all, why did you expect this to work?

Comment: try `bal(**wallet1)`

Comment: @juanpa - New to python did not know what needed to be changed. And that is how I wound up on stackoverflow.

Comment: @FrankAK - That gives the balance for one of the wallets, but I want to get the balance of all the wallets in the list "wallets".

Comment: @But youe `bal` function only parser the one at each call! if your do really want to check every wallets, you should define a second function calll `many_bal` something like this and then make a loop and call at the inside !

Comment: `def many_bal(wallets): return [bal(**w) for w in wallets]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

```
for w in wallets:
   print(bal(**w))
```

the solution requires understanding two different concepts, loops and argument unpacking

you can't call

```
bal(wallets)
```

because that is calling the function `bal(<list>)` which doesn't exist...(your function has three args, not one). Since your `bal` function expects a single wallet, we simply call it one time for each wallet in your list.

Your function is still expecting three args though, so we can't just pass `w` since it's a dictionary.  You can use a bit of python syntactical sugar to automatically pull the values out of the dictionary and pass them to the function as named arguments. so `bal(**w)` will behave as `bal(address=<the value of address>, symbol=<val...>, name=<val...>)`.

One thing to remember with using this approach is that argument unpacking will pass *ALL* key/vals in the dict to the function, so if you add something unexpected, you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

function 'bal' expects to take 3 arguments.

you call bal with one argument hence why it complains it is missing 2 (3 - 1 = 2).

you need to modify your bal function so it can take one argument only e.g.

```
def bal(wallets):
```

and extract wallet dictionaries from passed argument by e.g. iterating through it:

```
for w in wallets
```

so now you can access `'address, symbol, name'` from `w` dict e.g.:

```
address = w['address']
symbol = w['sumbol']
name = w['name']
```

here is the code that should work for you:

```
def bal(wallets):
    elems_all = []
    for w in wallets:
        address = w['address']
        symbol = w['symbol']
        name = w['name']

        r = requests.get('https://bitinfocharts.com/' + name + '/address/' + address)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        elems = soup.find('div', itemprop = 'offers').contents[0].text
        elems = elems.replace(symbol,'').strip()
        elems_all.append([elems, w])

    return elems_all
```

it is very basic implementation but it works for you. you may want to modify it to use more beautiful Python implementation.

you can access right elems for with wallet by accessing elems_all list of tuples.

Comment: I saw the updated code but I am now getting the error - TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: sorry, I shall have tested it before I added the edit. elems_all.append(elems, w) change to list elems_all.append([elems, w]) or tuple elems_all.append((elems, w))

Comment: Is there any easy way to append the balances to the dictionaries?

Comment: hey Tommy, I do recommend you to work out Python basics and data types operations before you start asking further questions. just search for Python dictionary operations. Dictionary is build of key:value pairs. to append a k:v pair to dict:    dict1['k1']='v1'